# Are all of these Dexes just frontend interface to coin swapping contracts? Uniswap, 1inch, balance defi-swap, shibaswap, etc

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, sushiswap, amm, balancer

I'm still wrapping my head around all these swapping services like Uniswap, sushiswap, etc...

- Uniswap
- Sushiswap
- 1 Inch
- Balancer
- Defiswap
- Shibaswap

Are all those above just front end interface to swap coins? Is there a central smart contract that all these systems connect to to do its swaps?

I thought all of these other swapping or AMM systems just interacted with Uniswap itself. Is Uniswap the central smart contract that everything else runs through? I'm trying to get a clearer picture on how this all connects.

Comment: yes thats exactly how it works, but all of them have their own contract though. you can find contract sources on the net

Comment: So uniswap is just a front end only? but when you add ETH to a liquidity pool, it is shared among all those frontends?

Comment: no , each exchange has its own liquidity pool

Comment: most of those are clones of uniswap and they have their own contracts. So even though they work exactly the same, they are not connected and each have their own respective UI.

Comment: yep, only balancer and uniswap have their own ideas, every other exchange is a copycat. they do it for the trading fee, 0.2% of 1 billion is 2 million , for a copy of a contract and a copy of a GUI on a webserver ? very good money!

Comment: that's what Uniswap earns per day, approx

Comment: I have a great idea to bring the major decentralized exchanges together in one contract to give users the best value for money.What do you think?